# ping program not response the icmp error message

Tags: icmp

My operation like this: `ping -s 8950 10.10.1.100` .

I can capture the icmp error message(frag needed and DF set, mtu=8900) with `tcpdump` from the interface, but the ping program not frag packets according to mtu=8900.

I have checked the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit` is 1000, and the iptables is not run.

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Are you using jumbo frame ethernet?

Comment: I have set the mtu of interface to 9000

Comment: Just for sure. Can you share with us the `ip link show|grep mtu` output?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have solved this problem. The "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ens80/rp_filter" is set value 1, result in the icmp error packet was droped.